# Как правильно перевести словарь в датафрейм, где значения будут разделены по ключам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи от тех, кто решил в данную минуту заглянуть ко мне в данный вопрос. Скорее всего, решение задачи, с которой я столкнулся, довольно легкое, однако мне нужна помощь от вас в этом вопросе. Спасибо заранее <3

Задача:

- нужно перевести готовый словарь в датафрейм с данными формата word | genre (колонки), и сохранить в какую-либо переменную.

Следующий словарь:

```
genre_dict = {
    'комедия': ['сатирический', 'авантюрный', 'забавный'],
    'мелодрама': ['выбор', 'позор'],
    'сказка': ['приключения', 'милый', 'семейный'],
    'детектив': ['тайна', 'разгадать', 'загадочный'], 
    'триллер': ['ужас', 'зловещий', 'нерв']
}
```

...нужно превратить в такой датафрейм:

| genre | word |
| --- | --- |
| комедия | сатирический |
| комедия | авантюрный |
| комедия | забавный |
| мелодрама | выбор |
| мелодрама | позор |
| сказка | приключения |
| сказка | милый |
| сказка | семейный |
| детектив | тайна |
| детектив | разгадать |
| детектив | загадочный |
| триллер | ужас |
| триллер | зловещий |
| триллер | нерв |

Однако, когда я пытаюсь воссоздать датафрейм из словаря следующим кодом:

```
genres_df = pd.DataFrame(genre_dict.items(), columns=['genres', 'word'])
genres_df['genres'] = genres_df['genres'].str.join(', ')
```

...у меня получается следующее:

```
| genre | word |
| --------- | ----------------------- |
| комедия | сатирический, авантюрный, забавный |
| мелодрама | выбор, позор |
| сказка | приключения, милый, семейный |
| детектив | тайна, разгадать, загадочный |
| триллер | ужас, зловещий, нерв |
```

А это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Прошу помощи с решением этого вопроса. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k,x] for k,v in genre_dict.items() for x in v], 
                  columns=["genre","word"])
```

результат:

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]:
        genre          word
0     комедия  сатирический
1     комедия    авантюрный
2     комедия      забавный
3   мелодрама         выбор
4   мелодрама         позор
5      сказка   приключения
6      сказка         милый
7      сказка      семейный
8    детектив         тайна
9    детектив     разгадать
10   детектив    загадочный
11    триллер          ужас
12    триллер      зловещий
13    триллер          нерв
```

---

Также можно получить необходимый результат из вашего `genres_df`, воспользовавшись методом [DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
genres_df = pd.DataFrame(genre_dict.items(), columns=['genres', 'word'])

In [75]: genres_df.explode("word")
Out[75]:
      genres          word
0    комедия  сатирический
0    комедия    авантюрный
0    комедия      забавный
1  мелодрама         выбор
1  мелодрама         позор
2     сказка   приключения
2     сказка         милый
2     сказка      семейный
3   детектив         тайна
3   детектив     разгадать
3   детектив    загадочный
4    триллер          ужас
4    триллер      зловещий
4    триллер          нерв
```

Comment: работает как надо, спасибо большое:)